# GRASS's r.in.lidar error in QGIS 3: "North must be north of South"

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, lidar, qgis-3, las

I have LAZ files that I unpacked with laszip.exe, then I ended up with LAS files.

These files showed no error when making a LAS dataset in ArcGIS.
I used this dataset several times without ant issues.

But when trying to use `r.in.lidar` in QGIS, I get this error:

> ERROR: North must be north of South.

Since the files worked in ArcGIS, I am thinking this is a software or setup issue I have in QGIS.

I can't find that error message anywhere on the interweb.

Comment: Have you tried it in the stand alone GRASS that comes with QGIS? If you do so, you could print the output of `g.region -p` and `r.in.lidar -sg input=(las file here) output=dummy -o`

Answer (score 3):

I am reading the man page of GRASS 7:

> Since the r.in.lidar generates a raster map through binning from the original LiDAR points, the target computational region extent and
> resolution have to be determined. A typical workflow would involve the
> examination of the LAS data's associated documentation or the scan of
> the LAS data file with r.in.lidar's -s (or -g) flag to find the input
> data's bounds.
>
> Another option is to automatically set the region extents based on the LAS dataset extent (-e flag) along with the desired raster
> resolution using the resolution parameter. [Link to Source](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass74/manuals/r.in.lidar.html)

My guess is that you need to look at the options you are using and set a proper region extent

Answer (score 0):

I used "System Administrator" to execute QGIS with GRASS and the error would not show.

Comment: Can you explain a little more?